# Array in a specific format in csv file using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I am trying to save the array `inv_r` in a specific format in a csv file. The current and the desired formats are attached.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

inv_r=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],
                [16,17,18,19,20],
                [21,22,23,24,25]])
data = [inv_r]

with open('inv_r.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the data
    writer.writerows(zip(inv_r))
```

The current format is

[image]

The desired format is

[image]

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `writer.writerows(zip(inv_r))`, what is the intended purpose of `zip`? Where the code says `data = [inv_r]`, what is the intended purpose of that? What structure do you expect the data to have as a result? According to the documentation for `writer.writerows`, what should the input look like, in order to get the result you want?

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Without the ```zip```, it works. However, it still skips a line between each row.

Comment: What tool are you using to view the CSV file? Make sure that it understands the same line endings that Python is writing.

Comment: I am using Excel to open the CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `zip`, first of all, so that each element get its own cell.

To remove the blank lines between each row, you need to add `newline=''` to the `open` call. See the footnote in the documentation for the `csv` library [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3) for an explanation as to why this is necessary.